# ssh to server and execute curl equivalent with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, python-requests, paramiko

I have this command:

```
ssh 111.222.333.444 curl -s -k https://123.456.789.876:4567/mock.crt -o /root/mock.crt
```

I'd like to include it, or the equivalent of it, in a Python application I'm writing. I think I need to use a combination of requests and paramiko to achieve this. So far I'vew come up with this:

```
  def add_certs(self):
      ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
      ssh.connect(111.222.333.444)
      url = 'https://123.456.789.876:4567/mock.crt'
      res = ssh.requests.get(url, verify=False)
      print("Add mock server certs: " + res.json())
```

I haven't had a chance to run this yet as the server is currently unavailable. I still haven't got the output writing to file, rather than stdout. How do I do this? Also, if there is anything wronw with the way I'm trying to do this I'd appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API in SSH protocol itself to make the server download a file and store it locally (on the server).

This is true in general, Python or not.

All you can do is to execute *some application or command* (like `curl` or similar) on the SSH server, to do it for you. In Python/Paramiko, you can use [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command).

---

*There might be a pure Python way to achieve, what you need, with some limitations. But we do not know your constraints, so I cannot elaborate.*